# Handle offline server in angular 5 service post request

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I'd like to handle it, when my node backend is gone. I'm using the MEAN-Stack and CORS-Middleware with `app.use(cors())`.

So i tried to use `rxjs timeout` in my request ->

```
return this.http.post('http://192.168.45.20:3000/bookings/', booking, {headers: headers})
    .timeout(3000)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

When my server is online, everything works fine, but directly when the request was send and my server is offline i get an error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://192.168.45.20:3000/bookings. (Reason:
>   CORS attack failed).

So how do i handle the server offline state inside my angular 5 service?

Comment: have you tried the rxjs retry operator?

Comment: After i got the CORS Error in Chrome no more requests are possible till site is refreshed, so i think `retry` would not have any effect or?

Comment: sorry i can't say extacly .. maybe give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to

- Add a caching logic to your angular application through a service worker(https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)
- Detect when network is unavailable (optionally you can give visual feedback to your user). With a localstorage saving system you can schedule updates when network is available thanks to replication system

PS : Http Interceptors are useful for that purpose

Comment: i already implemented everything like that but how should i check than for the backend to be available or not? Lets assume network is available at anytime, but my backend is not and i need to check that directly, but how within the request?

Comment: use catch operator from rxjs within the Http Interceptor (check the status)